# Use sections "inline"

Tags: sectioning, margins, titlesec

How can I get the startpoints for my sections (see top part of MWE) as one inline text, similar to what can be done with the bottom part of my MWE? I need the `sections` since my `title marks` etc work off them. Have a look at the part where the word "CATALAN" is in the example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec, marginnote}

% turns sections into arabic numbers
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

% sections and subsections formatting
% package = titlesec
\titleformat{\section}{}{\lettrine{\thesection}}{0em}{}[\vskip-1\baselineskip]
\titleformat{\subsection}[leftmargin]{\small\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{\howwide}{-1pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{1em}

\begin{document}

\subsection{}Babel and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, german-x-2011-07-01, ngerman-x-2011-07-01, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabic, armenian, basque, bulgarian,
\subsection{}CATALAN, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danish, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnish, french, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, hungarian, icelandic

\reversemarginpar

\marginnote{{\bf 1}}Babel and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, german-x-2011-07-01, ngerman-x-2011-07-01, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabic, armenian, basque, bulgarian,
\marginnote{{\bf 2}}CATALAN, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danish, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnish, french, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, hungarian, icelandic

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your lines don't have excessive depth, this can work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\marginsec}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{marginsec}%
  \mbox{\strut#1}\vadjust{\vbox to 0pt{
    \sbox0{\bfseries\themarginsec\quad}
    \kern-\ht0
    \kern-\dp\strutbox
    \llap{\box0 }
    \vfill
    }
  }%
}
\newcounter{marginsec}

\begin{document}
\marginsec{Babel} and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation,
german-x-2011-07-01, ngerman-x-2011-07-01, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabic,
armenian, basque, bulgarian,
\marginsec{CATALAN}, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danish, dutch, ukenglish,
usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnish, french, galician, german,
ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, hungarian, icelandic
\end{document}
```

Comment: You've hit the nail on the head on the look of it, but will the sections still work as normal for links in the TOC and bookmarks as well as the `titlesec` titlemarks? I'll try and implement this solution anyway to see for myself.

Comment: I think I got it all working. Changing `\refstepcounter{marginsec}` to `\refstepcounter{subsection}` and `\sbox0{\bfseries\themarginsec\quad}` to `\sbox0{\bfseries\thesubsection\quad}` and also deleting \newcounter{marginsec}. The `titlemarks` picks it up well enough.

Answer (score 3):

Do you men something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{%
  \@startsection{section}{1}{-1.5em}%
                            {1ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                            {0em}%
                            {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\begin{document}

\section{}Babel and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, german-x-2011-07-01, ngerman-x-2011-07-01, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabic, armenian, basque, bulgarian,
\section{}CATALAN, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danish, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnish, french, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, hungarian, icelandic

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but looking at your example, I want the CATALAN to follow straight after the bulgarian. The number 2 should then be displayed before the line reading "menian, basque, bulgarian, CATALAN..."