# To linenumber at start of sentences without altering data?

Tags: line-numbering

I have data which I do not want to change or duplicate it. 
I would like to have a line number after each empty line. 
It would be great if this can be done by some presentation only.

Data

```
This is a sentence. 

This is a sentence 2.
```

which should be shown like

```
1 This is a sentence. 

2 This is a sentence 2.
```

and you can choose where you show the number (margin next to the body etc).

How can you add such linenumbers at the start of each line?

Comment: Could you show how you would use this a minimal example? For example, wrapping the lines inside some magical environment, say...?

Comment: You could use sections. Have a look at Herbert and egreg's answers at this old question of mine. http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40748/7093

Answer (score 1):

In plain \TeX nique I would do it this way. "Each empty line", should be `\everypar`. I removed the need for empty lines by `\obeylines`.

```
\newdimen\linenowd\setbox0=\hbox{9999}\linenowd=\wd0
\newdimen\linenoskipamount\linenoskipamount=5pt
\newcount\lineno\lineno=1
\def\linenoskip{\hskip \linenoskipamount}
\def\beginlineno{\begingroup\obeylines\global\advance\lineno by -1\everypar={\global\advance\lineno by 1\hbox to \linenowd{\hfill\the\lineno\linenoskip}}}
\def\endlineno{\endgroup}

\beginlineno
This is a sentence.
This is another sentence.
\endlineno
\bye
```