# How to Remove All Whitespace around text?

Tags: spacing, margins

I would like to remove all spacing around text. Vertical and horizontal. I have solved this problem before but I cannot find the source. 
I want to read the document on my phone's screen which is small and I need all space there.

Stub start

```
\documentclass{article}

%%% I need to have these things in the body. 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % for pipe symbol
%% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40748/use-sections-inline
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{%
  \@startsection{section}{1}{-1.5em}%
                            {1ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                            {0em}%
                            {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\begin{document}

\section{}What is the difference between | this | and | lorem | plaa.

\section{}What is the difference between | this | and | lorem | plaa.

\section{}What is the difference between | this | and | lorem | plaa.

\end{document}
```

---

How can you remove all Spacing around text?

Comment: Reading a pdf on a small screen is .... Better use some ebook-format..

Comment: ``\catcode`\ =9``?

Comment: @HenriMenke What should your code do?

Comment: @Johannes_B I cannot understand what benefits the ebook would bring. You need to use Pandoc. Removing margins here seem to work fine.

Comment: @Masi Changes the category code of the space character to *invalid* making TeX ignore all the spaces.  This answers the part of your question where you say: »I would like to remove all spacing around text.«

Comment: @HenriMenke I think your answer is more general than just simply setting margin zero in the geometry package.

Comment: You want to read on your tablet, have presentations with videos, want to make LaTeX ignore comments (so that they are no longer comments). You want to do a lot of stuff, and i think you should not use LaTeX for most of it. Your ideas and thoughts can be put down in simple text, but you need different ways to get the output you want. But this is my personal way of thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>An answer to the [first version](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/310776/1) of the question.</sub>

## Class `standalone`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}

lorem ipsum

\end{document}
```

Full page:

[image: Result]

## Settings the margins to zero

```
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}
```

## Cropping the PDF file

Or the PDF file can be post-processed with `pdfcrop` to remove the outer margins.

Comment: @Masi Very unclear. Except for the different font encoding, the body of the document of the question does not use any of the things added to the preamble.